# Profile Image not displaying

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am currently doing an instagram clone project, and I have encountered a problem where the profile image is appearing broken. I have tried to echo out the path, and the problem is, despite this being the path specified:

```
/storage/app/public/profile/9UHe7CSRK4V9SNESMz0BAYggmQOp2G04J3Ygcgtl.png
```

The browser is returning this path

```
/storage/app/public/profile//9UHe7CSRK4V9SNESMz0BAYggmQOp2G04J3Ygcgtl.png
```

So you can see that the browser is adding a second '/' after profile, I don't know why.

Here is my index.blade

```
<div class="col-3 p-5">
            <img src="{{ dd($user->profile->profileImage()) }}" class="rounded-circle w-100">

</div>
```

My Profile model

```
class Profile extends Model
{

        protected $guarded = [];

        public function profileImage()
        {
            $imagePath = ($this->image) ?  $this->image : 'profile/9UHe7CSRK4V9SNESMz0BAYggmQOp2G04J3Ygcgtl.png';

            return '/storage/app/' . $imagePath;
        }
```

Profiles controller

```
class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        
        return view('profiles.index', compact('user'));
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $user->profile);

        return view('profiles.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $user->profile);

        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' =>'required',
            'description' =>'required',
            'url' =>'url',
            'image' =>'',
        ]);
        
        

        if(request()->hasfile('image')){
            $imagePath = request()->file('image')->store('profile', 'public');
            
            $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
            $image->save();
        }
        
        auth()->user()->profile->update(array_merge(
            $data,
            ['image' => $imagePath]
        ));

        return redirect("/Profile/{$user->id}");
       
    }

}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/p/create', [App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::class, 'create'])->name('posts.create');

Route::get('/p/{post}', [App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::class, 'show']);

Route::post('/p', [App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::class, 'store']);

Route::get('/Profile/{user}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class, 'index'])->name('Profile.show');

Route::get('/Profile/{user}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class, 'edit'])->name('profiles.edit');

Route::patch('/Profile/{user}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class, 'update'])->name('profiles.update');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to use `asset()` instead of adding `storage/app` try to `return asset($imagePath)` in your method `profileImage()`

Answer (score 0):

You could load it into base64 with this PHP code:

```
$type = pathinfo(dd($user->profile->profileImage()), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents(dd($user->profile->profileImage()));
$imgbase64 = "data:image/" . $type . ";base64," . base64_encode($data);
```

then use

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgbase64; ?>" class="rounded-circle w-100">
```

This will then display the base64 image, which doesn't store the URL in plain text.